# Loading file in python

Tags: python, load, newline

I'm having some problems with the following code:

```
with open('townhall.map', 'r') as f:
    for line in f: 
        for character in line:
            if character == "x":
                print "WALL"
            else:
                if character == "a":
                    print "LAND"
                else:
                    print "Unexpected Error loading map!"
```

townhall.map:

```
xxxxx
xaaax
xaaax
xaaax
xxxxx
```

The problem I have is that it reads the newlines as characters; so I get this on output -

```
WALL
WALL
WALL
WALL
WALL
Unexpected Error loading map!
WALL
LAND
LAND
LAND
WALL
Unexpected Error loading map!
WALL
LAND
LAND
LAND
WALL
Unexpected Error loading map!
WALL
LAND
LAND
LAND
WALL
Unexpected Error loading map!
WALL
WALL
WALL
WALL
WALL
```

How do I make it ignore newline 'characters'?

Comment: At the risk of being pedantic, I just want to emphasize that newlines aren't 'characters'. They _really are_ characters, just like 'a', 'b', and 'c'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change this line:

```
for character in line.rstrip():
```

And you can also make the if/else structure flatter:

```
with open('townhall.map', 'r') as f:
    for line in f: 
        for character in line.rstrip():
            if character == "x":
                print "WALL"
            elif character == "a":
                print "LAND"
            else:
                print "Unexpected Error loading map!"
```

or define the printing as a dictionary:

```
char = {'x': 'WALL',
        'a': 'LAND'}
with open('townhall.map', 'r') as f:
    for line in f: 
        for character in line.rstrip():
            try:
                print char[character]
            except KeyError:
                print "Unexpected Error loading map!"
```

Comment: +1; the second example is much more extensible than the awful chain of `elif`s you'll end up with if you start adding more terrain types.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do that. One of them is:

```
with open('townhall.map', 'r') as f:
    for line in f: 
        for character in line:
            if character in ['x','a']:
                if character == "x":
                    print "WALL"
                else:
                    if character == "a":
                        print "LAND"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to account for your newline character as well, and ignore it.

```
with open('townhall.map', 'r') as f:
    for line in f: 
        for character in line:
            if character == "x":
                print "WALL"
            elif character == "a":
                print "LAND"
            elif character == "\n":
                pass
            else:
                print "Unexpected Error loading map!"
```